# How to change text colour based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Changing the colour of the marks obtained by a student - if < 40 then red else black.

I have a table in a PHP file displaying marks obtained in various subjects.  Below 40 marks should be shown in red.

```
echo "<td>".$res['marks1i']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$res['marks1e']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$res['marks2i']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$res['marks2e']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$res['marks3i']."</td>";    
echo "<td>".$res['marks3e']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Javascript:**

You can add a class name to each of the `td`'s that have marks (say 'marks'), then:

```
var marks = document.getElementsByClassName('marks');
for (const element in marks) {
  if(element.innerHTML < 40) {
    element.style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

Comment: Created a class ".marks", added your script after the table headings and before table data.  Added classname to <td>.  But still it is not working.  Marks are saved as varchar in the database.  Adding  parseInt()  like this - `for(const parseInt(element) in marks)` is not working - anything more to be added?

Answer (score 1):

Would that solve your problem?:

```
foreach ($res as $mark)  echo '<td style="color:'.$mark < 40 ? 'red' : 'black'.'">'.$mark.'</td>';
```